# SQL query where I get a single column as an array

Tags: sql, csv, common-workflow-language

Here is my data

```
customer_id, user_id, value, year
c1, u1, 100, 2022
c1, u2, 200, 2022
c1, u3, 300, 2022
```

I want to get values of all the users of customer `c1` in an array after a sql query. How do I achieve that?

`SELECT value FROM table WHERE customer_id="c1" AND year="2022"` gives me something like

```
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|  100  |
|  200  |
|  300  |
```

I want a query that returns this instead

```
values
[100, 200, 300]
```

I tried asking chatgpt this question and it simply asked me to do
`SELECT ARRAY(SELECT value FROM table WHERE customer_id="c1" AND year="2022") as values`
But I dont think its correct. But I think chatgpt understood what I was trying to do. Hopefully my question is clear from this fake sql query as well.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...? Array functions are highly vendor-specific.

Comment: @GMB Hey I'm actually using csvq to parse a csv file. I tried putting csvq in the tags but it didn't allow me to. I need to make use of csvq because its part of a command line workflow. But I'm interested in knowing how its done in general also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LISTAGG is what you need in csvq.

I don't have csvq but try this:

```
 ---     ||  this column is the LISTAGG function similar to concat() or Concatenate()
 ---     ||  it is joining the value that would be individual row results into a ',' delimited string
 ---     ||                     || within the listagg grouping (all in this case, 
 ---     ||                     || but you could group on the customer_id and year and remove these
 ---     ||                     || qualifiers from the WHERE syntax below
 ---     ||                     ||           || this sets the order of the values in the list
 ---     ||                     ||           ||              
 SELECT LISTAGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) as "values"
 from data.csv 
 WHERE customer_id="c1" AND year="2022")
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I think this is what Im looking for. But I didn't really get this query. Can you explain it a little bit. Also theres a syntax error in the query I think.

Comment: `SELECT LISTAGG(value, ',') as values from data.csv WHERE customer_id="c1"` This query is working for me.

Comment: But when I add `ORDER BY value` in the end, the LISTAGG is not showing the ordered values

Comment: I updated the query above and added some documentation.  It appears to be all nuances of how to use LISTAGG().  I hope it helps or let me know if I need to format it another way.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Murphy, Now order by works as well. Thanks for the explanation too.

Comment: Is there a generic way of any sql query that results in single column, converted into a list? Because now I want to do a LIMIT on this, and the amount with which I need to LIMIT is based on the COUNT of the usage query result

Comment: The short answer is no, each database engine vendor can have their own implementation of T-SQL or ANSI-SQL and then add additional functions on top of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mySQL, you can do something like this, by using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ', '), ']') 'values' FROM table WHERE customer_id="c1" AND year="2022"
```